# Error 2440 cannot convert from 'int' to 'node'

Tags: c++, linked-list

Ok, so I'm working on a school assignment. I found this program that I wanted to use as an example to help me understand how the linked list system works. This specific program is supposed to create a linked list, and then ask the user to input "points" as in, an x and y pair. It stores each "point" in a node in the list and then should be able to print them all out. When I try to compile it though, i get 2 errors where it tells me that i can't convert from 'int' to 'node' and i have no idea why it is saying that. It looks like the syntax is the same as in the book so I must just be missing a small detail.

On a side note, this program is a random thing I found to use as an example, so if possible, could anyone fill me in on how to make it cout the x and y coords at the end there? It's written there in comments that it still needs to be done.

Here's the full error message:(the errors occur on line 44 and 67, both the lines that say "newNode->info = input;" )

Error   1   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'node *'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <cassert>
#include <ostream>



using namespace std;

struct node
{
node *info;
node *link;
int x, y; 
};

node* getXandY();

int main()
{
return 0;
}//end main

node* getXandY()
{
node *newNode, *first, *last; 

int input;
int count = 0;

cout << "Enter as many points as you like: (x,y)" << endl;
first = NULL;

do 
{
    //x integers
    cout << "Enter an X value: ";
    cin >> input;//read info
    int x = input; //store info (x) into input

    newNode = new node();//allocate memory for the type node
    assert(newNode != NULL);//terminate program is no memory space

    newNode->info = input;//copy value into input
    newNode->link = NULL;

    if (first == NULL)
    {
        first = newNode;
        last = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        last->link = newNode;
        last = newNode;
    }


    //y integers
    cout << "Enter an Y value: ";
    cin >> input;//get info
    int y = input;//store in for (y) into input

    newNode = new node;//allocate memory for the type node
    assert(newNode != NULL);//terminate program is no memory space

    newNode->info = input;//copy value into input
    newNode->link = NULL;

    if (first == NULL)
    {
        first = newNode;
        last = newNode;
    }//end if
    else
    {
        last->link = newNode;
        last = newNode;
    }//end else 
}//end do
while (input != 999);


for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    cout << "("  /*place code here x value <<*/  "," << /*place code here y value <<*/   ")" <<endl;    
}//end for
getchar(); 
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the full error messages, instead of your summary of what they say?

Comment: You probably want to change the type of `info` to `int`, instead of a `node *`.

Comment: `new` does it return a null pointer on failure, it throws an exception. You're also missing a return statement.

Answer (score 0):

The program is wrong and makes no sense.

As for the error, it occurs in statements like this

```
newNode->info = input;
```

The type of data member `info` is `node *`. See the definition of info

```
node *info;
```

while the type of `input` is `int`

```
int input;
```

So the compiler is unable to assign an object of type `int` to an object of type `node *`. Moreover variable input is a local variable. So in any case this code makes no sense.

I would define the list the following way

```
class list
{
public:
    typedef size_t size_type;
    typedef std::pair<int, int> value_type;

private:
   struct node
   {
      node *next;
      std::pair<int, int> point; 
   };
   node *head = nullptr, *tail = nullptr;
   size_type sz = 0;     

public:
   // Some special member functions and other methods as for example push_back or push_front
   size_type size() const { return sz; }
   //...
};
```